# How do I secure the backends in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

If I am using MS Access for a frontend, to link to some databases in the backend, how do I prevent people from browsing to the relevant folders and copying/deleting the databases themselves?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify what version of MS Access you are using

Answer (score 3):

There are several options.  Please refer to this link:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-securing-a-microsoft-access-database/552/

The best options are hiding the db browsing options, and password-protecting the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't secure the backends in MS Access against people who have permission to use them. You can only hide them. Windows does have support for secure authorisation only for signed applications, but Access has never implemented those methods.

You prevent users from browsing to the relevant folders by

(1) (As discussed in other answers) Hiding the name of the folders, so that people don't know where they are.

(2) Hiding the folders, so that people can't see them unless they have permission to see hidden folders.

(3) Removing "List Folder Contents" permission from a top-level folder, so that people don't have permission to browse to the relevent folder.

You can also prevent people from accidently deleting a database by removing the delete permission from the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do. Code is not mine, I just put it toghether based on two months of research I did. Don't get a false sense of security, however, because passwords are in the connection string, so they can be easily hacked, and you have to find the way to control who links to the db from another db, or else they can still dig into the data:

1. Disable Object menu
2. Disable Ribbon. Use AutoExec to run: HideTheRibbon()

Function HideTheRibbon()
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
End Function

1. Disable Shift Key Entering, by putting code in an OnClick even of a form "frmByPassOption" for example. Make sure to change the pasword to something you can remember because once this is in place, no one, including Jesus, will be able to get in ther and change the code.

Disallow F11 key whith the KeyPreview options

```
'***************** Code Start ***************
'Assign this to the OnClick event of a command button (or double-click event
'of a label or graphic) named "bDisableBypassKey"
'Change the "TypeYourBypassPasswordHere" default password to your password

Private Sub bDisableBypassKey_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click
    'This ensures the user is the programmer needing to disable the Bypass Key
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    Beep
    strMsg = "Do you want to enable the Bypass Key?" & vbCrLf & vbLf & "Key password to enable Bypass Key."
    strInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, title:="Disable Bypass Key Password")
    If strInput = "carlo12a" Then
        SetProperties "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, True
        Beep
        MsgBox "Bypass Key has been enabled." & vbCrLf & vbLf & "Shift key will allow users to bypass startup" & _
               "options next time database is opened.", _
               vbInformation, "Set Startup Properties"
    Else
        Beep
        SetProperties "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False
        MsgBox "Incorrect ''AllowBypassKey'' Password!" & vbCrLf & vbLf & "The Bypass Key was disabled." & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
               "The Shift key will NOT allow the users to bypass the startup options the next time the database is opened.", _
               vbCritical, "Invalid Password"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
    MsgBox "bDisableBypassKey_Click", Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click
End Sub
'***************** Code End ***************
```

Put this code under  public module:

```
'***************** Code Start ***************
'Copy this function into a new public module.

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function SetProperties(strPropName As String, varPropType As Variant, varPropValue As Variant) As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Dim db As DAO.Database, prp As DAO.Property

    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Properties(strPropName) = varPropValue
    SetProperties = True
    Set db = Nothing

Exit_SetProperties:
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = 3270 Then    'Property not found
        Set prp = db.CreateProperty(strPropName, varPropType, varPropValue)
        db.Properties.Append prp
        Resume Next
    Else
        SetProperties = False
        MsgBox "SetProperties", Err.Number, Err.Description
        Resume Exit_SetProperties
    End If
End Function
'***************** Code End ***************
```